# ASP.NET Core web service does not load appsettings.json into configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Application with Razor Pages which has AAD authentication information defined in the `appsettings.json` file (courtesy of the default application template - see below on how I got there). However, when trying to configure the authentication in `Startup.cs` the configuration does not have any of the config values from my `appsettings.json`. If I inspect the `IConfiguration` object in the debugger then it appears to only have the environment variable configurations:

[image]

Here's the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method where the issue lies:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options =>
        {
            // This is from the default template. It should work, but the relevant settings aren't there so options isn't populated.
            this.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

            // This of course works fine
            options.Instance = "MyInstance";
            options.Domain = "MyDomain";
            options.TenantId = "MyTenantId";
            options.ClientId = "MyClientId";
            options.CallbackPath = "MyCallbackPath";
        });

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

And the service configuration in case it's important (note that this is being built on top of a service fabric stateless service):

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
            new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                return new WebHostBuilder()
                            .UseKestrel(opt =>
                            {
                                int port = serviceContext.CodePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoint("ServiceEndpoint").Port;
                                opt.Listen(IPAddress.IPv6Any, port, listenOptions =>
                                {
                                    listenOptions.UseHttps(GetCertificateFromStore());
                                    listenOptions.NoDelay = true;
                                });
                            })
                            .ConfigureServices(
                                services => services
                                    .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .UseStartup<Startup>()
                            .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                            .UseUrls(url)
                            .Build();
            }))
    };
}
```

To create this service, I used the wizard in VS2017. I selected an existing service fabric project (`.sfproj`) and chose `Services > Add > New Service Fabric Service` and chose `Stateless ASP.NET Core [for .NET Framework]`, then on the next page I chose `Web Application` (the one with Razor Pages, not MVC) and clicked `Change Authentication` where I chose `Work or School Accounts` and entered my AAD info. The only changes I have made to this template were adding the code inside the call to `AddAzureAD` in `Startup.ConfigureServices` and setting the `appsettings.json` files to always be copied to the output directory.

**Why doesn't the `appsettings.json` file get loaded into the configuration?** As I understand, this is supposed to happen by default, but something seems to be missing...

Comment: `WebHostBuilder` doesn't load `appsettings.json` by default, you need to manually call `AddJsonFile`.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. Sure enough, that solved my problem. Instead of doing that I actually replaced `new WebHostBuilder()` with `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()`, but why the template doesn't work out of the box is beyond me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that will also load the config. I believe it was change in 2.0, perhaps your template is an older one?

Comment: It's possible. Who knows when the templates were last updated, but they're apparently not tested very thoroughly

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`WebHostBuilder` doesn't load `appsettings.json` by default, you need to manually call `AddJsonFile`. For example:

```
return new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel(opt =>
            {
                //snip
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
            })
            .ConfigureServices(
                services => services
                    .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
            .UseUrls(url)
            .Build();
```

Alternatively you can use [`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which will load more defaults.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach, would be to manually create the configuration via `ConfigurationBuilder` then use the `UseConfiguration` method.

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
     .Build();

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
     .UseConfiguration(configuration)
     .UseKestrel()
     .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

The primary intent is core to provide a bit of flexibility when implementing, they often error on less is more.  You have to explicitly say what you would like, that way the pipeline remains relatively small.

Answer (score 4):

For others like me who find this issue:

It might be that you're not copying the appsettings.json file during build.

The OP **does** say he's doing this, but it's kind of a small print thing - and was what I was failing to do.

The more you know ...

Answer (score 2):

Below mentioned steps worked for me

1. Go to Appsettings.json
2. Right click and goto properties
3. select the build action from the drop down to none if its content
4. Make the copy to Output directory as Copy Always

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before `WebHostBuilder` do not execute this default behavior `CreateDefaultBuilder` needs to be called instead.

I prefer following implementation:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
     var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

     try
     {
         logger.LogInformation("Starting up");
                
         host.Run();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         logger.LogCritical(ex, "Application start-up failed");
      }
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your file name is all lower case.**

My mistake was to name the file `appSettings.json` instead of `appsettings.json`. When running within a Linux container, the camel-cased file was not loaded.